# Are binding redirects inside assembly.dll.config ever evaluated at runtime?

Tags: .net, clr

According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions) assembly binding redirects can also be inside `assembly.dll.config` not just in `assembly.exe.config`. But the docs are not really clear whether binding redirects inside `assembly.exe.config` can also be used at runtime.

If I deploy a `assembly.dll.config` together with the `assembly.dll` in the the app, will, the binding redirects in there ever have any effect?

Comment: No.  This is clumsy language, be sure to read it as "You can override this default behavior for any assembly by providing binding redirection information in the app.config file".  Show us that I'm wrong by actually trying it.

Comment: "app.config" is also misleading because DLL-projects can also have an app.config (which is compiled to `assembly.dll.config`).

Comment: The word "app" is not very misleading, it never means "library".  That msbuild slovenly renames it to foo.dll.config is not technically wrong, custom CLR hosts can use it to initialize their appdomain.

Comment: Correct, but in the context of this question it is quite misleading because a DLL can have a file that actually named `app.config`. So saying "any assembly" and "app.config" in the same sentence is still confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Binding redirects are not used from `assembly.dll.config`.

If BindingRedirect.exe calls LibBindingRedirect.dll :

- BindingRedirect.exe.config (work)
- LibBindingRedirect.dll.config (don't work)